# Hashing MongoDB ID using solidity

Tags: mongodb, hex

Can i hash mongodb Id which in this case is represented by demoId? and if can, what would be the solution? Thanks

i tried the following ways (being aware that mongodb Id is 12 byte) but get errors

when I set the type to bytes12 in soliditySha3, i get following error invalid bytes12 for 0x....

when i set the type to bytes16 in soliditySha3, i get following error invalid bytes16 for 0x...

```
 const demoIdHex = web3 && web3.utils.utf8ToHex(demoId!);
  console.log("demoIdHex", demoIdHex);

  const orderHash =
    web3 &&
    web3.utils.soliditySha3(
      { type: "bytes16", value: demoIdHex },
      { type: "address", value: account.data }
    );  // THIS FUNCTION FAILED
  console.log("orderHash", orderHash);
```

Comment: Have you checked what `web3.utils.utf8ToHex(demoId!)` is returning?

Comment: hi @Joe, it returns 0x363162343665343234666136643333653736373233613665

Comment: That's 24 bytes.  Did `demoId` contain a string instead of an objectid?

Comment: i see. That makes sense. I passed the entire mongoId as a string to the utf8ToHex function. That probably causes the error. I just tried converting the string id to ObjectId and passed it into the utf8ToHex function but it doesn't work. the utf8ToHex function only takes in string

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with some help

no need to use utf8ToHex

simply do below for mongoId

```
const orderHash =
  web3 &&
  web3.utils.soliditySha3(
    { type: "bytes12", value: demoId! },
    { type: "address", value: account.data }
  );
```